# xcode 6.1.1 doesn't compile: AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m:455:9: Use of undeclared identifier '_cancelled'

Tags: xcode6, afnetworking

I have a working project already in App Store, today I've upgraded Xcode to 6.1.1 and compiled my project and got the following error:

```
AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m:455:9: Use of undeclared identifier '_cancelled'
```

AFURLConnectionOperation is derived from NSOperation in which the cancelled property is defined like so:

```
@property (readonly, getter=isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;
- (void)cancel;
```

In xcode 5.1.1 the parameter was recognized and for some reason in xcode 6 (with support of ios 8) it's no longer recognizing it's parent property

suggestions?